# Extending a 2-frame field - manifolds with boundary

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, obstruction-theory

It is known that every smooth manifold can be homotoped to a cell complex.

In particular this is true for manifolds with boundary.

My question: Under the homotopy to a cell complex, is the boundary homotoped to a co-dimension 1 sub-complex?

Assuming the above is true I claim:

> If $M$ is an orientable compact 3-manifold with boundary such that there is
>   defined $s\in\Gamma(\partial M,V_2(TM))$ a section of the 2-frame bundle of $TM$,
>   then $s$ extends to $\tilde s\in\Gamma(M,V_2(TM))$

**Proof:**

*Step 1*

I define $\tilde s=s$ on $\partial M^{(1)}$, the 1-skeleton of $\partial M$.

*Step 2*

I extend $\tilde s$ over $M^{(1)}$, because $\pi_0(SO_3)=0$.

*Step 3*

I then extend it over $M^{(2)}$ (because $w_2(M)$ vanishes for any orientable compact 3-manifold, due to the Wu formula and the vanishing of $w_1(M)$ as $M$ is orientable)

*Step 4*

Now, having obtained $\tilde s$ in particular on $\partial M^{(2)}$, I can homotope $\tilde s$ to $s$ over $\partial M^{(2)}$, because they already agree on $\partial M^{(1)}$ and the obstruction to homotoping over the 2-skeleton is just $\pi_2(SO_3)$ which is the trivial group.

*Step 5*

Now, having obtained $\tilde s$ over $M^{(2)}$, we extend it to all of $M$, because again, the obstruction to extending over the 3-skeleton is the trivial group $\pi_2(SO_3)$.

I need this reviewed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $M$ is a torus with a hole removed (giving a boundary circle), the retraction will give a wedge of two circles, and the boundary circle of the torus maps nontrivially to this wedge.  Therefore it does not map to a codimension 1 subcomplex.